# What about the 'this' variable for models in embedded documents?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I'm kind of new in node.js and sails but it's easy so I like it :)
I'm working actually with the sails Framework 0.10rc3 with MongoDB ans sails-mongo.

I know that the contributors of waterline are not big fan of embedded documents in models as for mongodb (https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/issues/44#issuecomment-35561040) but anyway, I wanted to know how the 'this' variable works in them and how to retrieve the current element in the inner-array.

Here is an exemple of model (that we can call ProjetSpan):

```
module.exports = {

attributes: {

        proj: 
        {
            model:'Projet'
        },

        spans:
        {
            start:
            {
                type: 'DATETIME',
                required: true,
                datetime: true,
                before: function() {
                    if (this.end < this.proj.end)
                        return this.end;
                    else
                        return this.proj.end;
                }
            },

            end:
            {
                type: 'DATETIME',
                required: true,
                datetime: true,
                after: function() {
                    if (this.start > this.proj.start)
                        return this.start;
                    else
                        return this.proj.start;
                }
            }
        }
}

};
```

how the 'this' will work in this case ? is 'this' a span (and so this.end will work and not this.proj.end) or is 'this' a ProjetSpan (ans so this.proj.end works but not this.end) ?

Finally, how to make this.end (the variable in the current span) and this.proj.end (the variable in the association of the current document) work in this embedded context ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waterline doesn't support embedded documents at all, except for supplying the `json` data type.  So, your model example won't work in Sails, and would need to be rewritten as something like:

```
module.exports = {

   attributes: {

    proj: {
        model:'projet'
    },

    spans: {
        type: 'json'
    },

    before: function() {

       if (this.spans.end < this.proj.end) {
          return this.spans.end;
       } else {
          return this.proj.end;
       }

    },

    after: function() {

       if (this.spans.start > this.proj.start) {
          return this.spans.start;
       } else {
          return this.proj.start;
       }

    }



}
```

In instance methods (like `before` and `after` here), `this` refers to the entire instance object.  You'll want to enhance that code with checks to make sure that `this.proj` is an object (i.e., that it was populated with `ProjetSpan.find({}).populate('project')`), and that `this.spans.end` and `this.spans.start` actually exist (since Waterline doesn't validate embedded JSON).

Comment: thank you :)
For the object check, I've made  `this.proj != null && typeof this.proj === 'object'` but what about `spans` ? At this state is it an object, an array, or something else ?

Comment: "spans" will be whatever JSON type you set it to; most likely an object or array. Unfortunately those are both `typeof` "object", but you can use `sails.util.isArray()` to test for arrays (`sails.util` wraps Lodash).

Comment: Cool thx :) ! I changed my models so following the recommendations, but at some point, what about deep associations test ? like `if ((this.projCollab != null && typeof this.projCollab === 'object') && (this.projCollab.proj != null && typeof this.projCollab.proj === 'object')) { if (this.end < this.projCollab.proj.end) return this.end; else return this.projCollab.proj.end; }` in a `before` function ? I know we can't make I for now, I've done some change for that, but It's still needed in some situations like this one..